# Handle button being long pressed

Tags: android, button, android-activity, view, kotlin

I would like my kotlin activity to execute an action when a button is pressed for a longer period of time instead of reacting after just a "quick" click. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Just like

```
button.setOnClickListener(...);
```

There is

```
button.setOnLongClickListener(...);
```